# Same code compiled two time generates files with different hash

Tags: macos, hash, makefile, md5, sha

When use make to compile my code and use MD5 or SHA1 to verify if the files are the same, the hash is different each time. Iam using OSX 10.7

My first guess was its because the files are created at different times so the time stamp which is save in the file is different therefore the file and hashes are different. But is this timestamp really hashed or left out like the filename?

If so, what is the best way to compare to compiled files to verify if they were compiled the same way?

EDIT:
Iam using the gcc 4.2.1

Comment: I think that answers to this question may well be compiler-dependent.  So go on, tell us what your compiler is ?

Comment: some object file formats include compilation time information. You could use a binary diff program, and ignore any observed differences you don't care about (such time related differences, or file path, or whatever).